# Change color button when text input are filed

Tags: react-native

I need to set the button to gray when the text input is empty and once ALL the fields are filled in, to change it to blue.

login.tsx

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import ButtonOutline from '../../../infrastructure/components/buttons/button-outline-primary/index';
import ButtonPrimary from '../../../infrastructure/components/buttons/button-primary/index';
import styles from './styles';
import { useForm, Controller } from 'react-hook-form';

export default function LogInComponent () {

```
const { register, setValue, handleSubmit, control, reset, formState: { errors } } = useForm();
const onSubmit = data => {
    console.log(data);
};



return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.boxTitle}>
                <Text>YPF - GAS</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.boxForm}>
                <View style={styles.boxInput1}>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>Patente</Text>
                    <Controller
                    control={control}
                    render={({field: { onChange, onBlur, value }}) => (
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.FormInput}
                        onBlur={onBlur}
                        onChangeText={value => onChange(value)}
                        value={value}
                    />
                    )}
                    name="patente"
                    rules={{required: true}}
                />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.boxInput}>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>Planta  </Text>
                    <Controller
                    control={control}
                    render={({field: { onChange, onBlur, value }}) => (
                    <TextInput 
                    style={styles.FormInput}
                    onBlur={onBlur}
                    onChangeText={value => onChange(value)}
                    value={value} 
                    />
                    )}
                    name="planta"
                    rules={{required: true}}
                />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.boxInput}>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>Usuario</Text>
                    <Controller
                    control={control}
                    render={({field: { onChange, onBlur, value }}) => (
                    <TextInput 
                    style={styles.UserFormInput}
                    onBlur={onBlur}
                    onChangeText={value => onChange(value)}
                    value={value}
                    />
                    )}
                    name="usuario"
                    rules={{required: true}}
                />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.boxButton}>
                    <ButtonOutline style={styles.button} title= 'Cerrar'></ButtonOutline>
                        <ButtonPrimary onPress={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} style={styles.button}  title= 'Ingresar'></ButtonPrimary>
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
);
```

}

---

styles.tsx

import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Colors from '../../../application/common/colors';

export default StyleSheet.create({
container: {
flex: 1,
backgroundColor: Colors.surface
},
boxTitle: {
flex: 1,
padding: 5,
alignItems: 'flex-start',
justifyContent: 'center',
backgroundColor: Colors.background
},
boxForm: {
flex: 9,
padding: 5
},
boxInput: {
flex: 0,
alignItems: 'center',
justifyContent: 'center',
flexDirection: 'row',
marginTop: 30
},
boxInput1: {
flex: 0,
alignItems: 'center',
justifyContent: 'center',
flexDirection: 'row',
marginTop: 70
},
FormInput: {
padding: 0,
lineHeight: 24,
fontSize: 20,
width: 168,
height: 40,
backgroundColor: Colors.background,
borderRadius: 4,
borderWidth: 2,
borderColor: '#AAAAAA',
},
UserFormInput: {
padding: 0,
fontSize: 20,
lineHeight: 24,
width: 168,
height: 40,
backgroundColor: Colors.surface,
borderRadius: 4,
borderWidth: 2,
borderColor: '#AAAAAA',
},
text: {
right: 60,
fontSize: 20,
lineHeight: 24
},
boxButton: {
top: 53,
flex: 1,
flexDirection: 'row',
justifyContent: 'space-around'
},
button: {
width: 216,
height: 40,
fontSize: 18,
lineHeight: 22
},

});

Comment: You should edit your post so that the code blocks are formatted correctly. 

Use the three ticks ` before and after the code block. 
It will make your code look more readable.

Example:

`var x = "Hello World!"`

Answer (score 0):

Use `TouchableOpacity` as Button in component

```js
    import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
    import {
      Text,
      View,
      StyleSheet,
      TextInput,
      TouchableOpacity,
    } from 'react-native';
    
    const ButtonColor = () => {
      const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
      const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');
      const [btnColor, setBtnColor] = useState(false);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        if (firstName !== '' && lastName !== '') {
          setBtnColor(true);
        } else {
          setBtnColor(false);
        }
      }, [lastName]);
    
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.secondContainer}>
            <View style={styles.formContainer}>
              <View style={styles.labelContainer}>
                <Text style={{color: '#000'}}>First Name</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.textContainer}>
                <TextInput
                  defaultValue={firstName}
                  placeholder={'Type First Name'}
                  onChangeText={val => setFirstName(val)}
                />
              </View>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.formContainer}>
              <View style={styles.labelContainer}>
                <Text style={{color: '#000'}}>Last Name</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.textContainer}>
                <TextInput
                  defaultValue={lastName}
                  placeholder={'Type Last Name'}
                  onChangeText={val => setLastName(val)}
                />
              </View>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.formContainer}>
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={
                  btnColor
                    ? styles.filledContainerButton
                    : styles.normalContainerButton
                }>
                <Text style={styles.btnTextColor}>Button</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      );
    };
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
      },
      secondContainer: {
        width: '85%',
        height: 300,
        marginTop: '40%',
        paddingHorizontal: 20,
        paddingVertical: 20,
        // alignItems: 'center',
        alignSelf: 'center',
        borderRadius: 5,
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderColor: 'black',
      },
      formContainer: {
        marginBottom: 20,
      },
      labelContainer: {
        marginBottom: 5,
      },
      textContainer: {
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#d3d3d3',
        borderRadius: 3,
        height: 40,
      },
      normalContainerButton: {
        backgroundColor: '#808080',
        height: 40,
        width: '80%',
        alignSelf: 'center',
        // alignContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        borderRadius: 9,
      },
      filledContainerButton: {
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
        height: 40,
        width: '80%',
        alignSelf: 'center',
        // alignContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        borderRadius: 9,
      },
      btnTextColor: {
        color: '#fff',
      },
    });
    
    export default ButtonColor;
```

Comment: I don’t think ‘btnColor’ needs to use ’useState’ since its value is decided exclusively by ‘useState’ variables

Comment: Thank youuu!!! Changing the text entries with useStates solved the problem for me. I had to delete the React Hook Form library.

Comment: Ram, how you submit the form?

Comment: @FrancoDorneles You can submit by having a submission method that contains whatever you like with an onPress attribute:

`<Button title="Contact Us" color="#708090" onPress={submit} />`

You would define the method to do whatever you need on submit and place the method name in that onPress part of the Button.